# Move an entire row to another sheet if it contains a specified word

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to find a code that would help me move an entire row to another sheet if it contains the word "Processing"  the original sheet is called "Output 1" and the sheet where i need to move it to is "Applications"  this is the code i found online but its giving me errors-Thanks ( i am not sure what d and j mean since i got it online)

```
Set i = Sheets("Output 1")  
Set e = Sheets("Applications")  
Dim d  
Dim j  
d = 1  
j = 2   
Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("B" & j))   
    If i.Range("B" & j) = "Processing" Then  
        d = d + 1  
        e.Rows(d).Value = i.Rows(j).Value   
    End If  
    j = j + 1  
Loop
```

Comment: What kind of error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Your code is not displaying correctly, is it really all on one line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim i As Worksheet, e As Worksheet
    Dim d, j

    Set i = Sheets("Output 1")
    Set e = Sheets("Applications")
    d = 1
    j = 2

    Do Until IsEmpty(i.Range("B" & j))
        If i.Range("B" & j) = "Processing" Then
            d = d + 1
            e.Rows(d).Value = i.Rows(j).Value
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: It did Thank you!!!! but it went into the first row and i have headers, how can it starts in the second row?

Comment: Never mind Is perfect! i had something else in the first raw and then the headers. Awesome!

Comment: `j` determines what row you want to start the loop

Comment: Is it me or did Tim edit the question to the answer? ^_^;

Comment: To be clear, not Dave's answer but Tim answered it via the edit. Just happens both arrived at same.